# Firebase google auth secure usage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, security, jwt, google-oauth

I've created a React-Firebase app and integrated gmail authentication.

When the user sign in the app get info like email, name, uid and stores it in session storage.

Is that a secure way to use info of clients

Also the info that I get when logging in is access token. I don't know how to take benefit of it.

Thanks.

app repo: https://github.com/amr099/React-Store

I am searching about JWT method for client authentication.

Should I use it to secure my client-side auth process ?